# Why does enabling a physicBody to my SKSpriteNode causes abnormalities?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift5, skphysicsbody

I have changed this question more than a bit, so I moved it to a new thread:
[How can I set a physicsbody to be properly centered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986142/how-can-i-set-a-physicsbody-to-be-properly-centered)

I am just starting with SKPhysicsBody, and I do have `view.showsPhysics = true`

Below is the code where I create a simple red border, which comes out just fine, and exactly where I would like it to be.

However, when I uncomment the two lines that apply `physicsBody` to the border, it moves unpredictably and even the physics debug lines from `view.showsPhysics = true` are out of sync with the border line.

Below is the code, and the screenshot provided on the left is what I want. The screenshot on the right shows what happens when I apply physicsBody to the SKSpriteNode.

Obviously I am applying something incorrectly, but I can't figure it out.

```
func createBorder () -> SKSpriteNode
{
    let mBorder = MyBorder(color: .red, size: CGSize(
                            width: myGlobalVars.widthPoints,
    height: myGlobalVars.heightPoints * 0.01 ))

    mBorder.isHidden = true
    mBorder.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    mBorder.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: myGlobalVars.heightPoints * 0.2)
//    mBorder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: myGlobalVars.widthPoints, height: myGlobalVars.heightPoints * 0.01))
//    mBorder.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false

    mBorder.zPosition = theZ.theBoarder
    mBorder.isHidden = false
    myGlobalVars.gameScene!.addChild(mBorder)

    return mBorder
}
```

p.s. Please ignore the first screen showing a gray bar. I had just changed the color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a more complete code example, it's hard to gauge why the red rectangular sprite has shifted downwards with dynamics turned on in the second screenshot.

As for the SpriteKit dynamics debug visualization looking wrong, that's happening because you're changing the sprites `anchorPoint` property. This attribute defines the node's *origin* point, as in the point that the node should be centered on (the default is `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`).

If you look at the documentation for the `SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:)` method, you'll see that by default the physics shape is created at the origin:

*Creates a rectangular physics body centered on the owning node’s origin.*

If you want to keep the sprite's `anchorPoint` at zero, you'll need to specify the center point of the physics shape manually. For the sake of this example, let's assume the border rectangle size you're looking for is **600x10**. You'll want to use the `SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:center:)` method to offset the physics body center:

```
let borderSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 10)
mBorder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: borderSize, center: CGPoint(x: borderSize.width / 2, y: borderSize.height / 2))
```

Comment: I was able to fix the physical body part by leaving the anchor point at 0.5, thank you. . But it still falls. And I am setting the affectedByGravity to false, so shouldn't the border wall NOT move. It's still falling, I'm adding a new picture to the OP to show. I will have that line be clear, so you can see just the physics debug lines –

Comment: The border will remain motionless if you set its physics body “isDynamic” property to false. Right now the border is only ignoring your scene’s gravity settings, but can still be affected by other physics bodies. I’d start troubleshooting there.

As an aside, SpriteKit physics can be quirky and sometimes testing them in a simulator can yield very different results than you would see on an actual iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code that you shared, it looks like you may need to set up some more details of the physics simulation. In any case, it might help you to debug your code if you can check the physics contacts with `print` statements to better understand what is and is not happening in your simulation. Here is how I'm handling physics in my own game; hopefully this example will be helpful.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
}
```

I set up the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` when declaring the `GameScene` class.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.balloon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 1.0)
    self.balloon.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    self.balloon.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    self.balloon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
}
```

Within that class, in the `didMove(to:)` method I set the `contactDelegate` for the `physicsWorld` to `self` which refers to the `GameScene`. Then I create the `physicsBody` for a balloon object that I created elsewhere in my scene. I see that you are already doing this in the part of your code which is commented out. I also set the category, contact, and collision bitmasks so that I can check them later.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == 0 {
        print("Balloon was contacted.")
    } else {
        print("No balloons hit.")
    }
}
```

In the `didBegin(_:)` method, when the engine calls this method each frame I examine the physics contacts and take some action in response to certain contacts that are occuring in the physics simulation. Here, I'm choosing to check the `categoryBitMask` for the contacted objects and if an object has a bitmask of `0` then I'm logging a `print` statement so that I know a balloon was hit by something. But I can just as easily take some other action instead.

If you want to find out more about checking for physics contacts and collisions, here are a few good resources to start with:

- [About Collisions and Contacts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/about_collisions_and_contacts)
- [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody)
- [bodyA](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicscontact/1478533-bodya)
- [bodyB](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicscontact/1478526-bodyb)